# Kubernetes add system variable to Dockers entrypoint

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, deployment, environment-variables

here's the problem. I've a Pod running in my cluster with angular. I want to use a System Variable in Dockers entrypoint. It would be very helpful for my use case.

According to my understanding the entrypoint is executed as soon as you pull the image in Kubernetes.

So my idea is to use a system variable in Dockers Entrypoint which will be initialized later during deployment. Kubernetes set the system variable and AFTER this, the entrypoint should be execute.

Do you have experience or do you see a mistake here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is a "System Variable"?

Comment: Environment variable

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Comment: I know how to set a env variable in kubernetes. Thats not my question :D

Comment: I want to manipulate the entrypoint of docker, i am to interested know if someone has experience if it works.

Comment: If you do the normal thing, Kubernetes will set _environment_ variables as described in the pod YAML specification and then run the image entrypoint (k8s command).  What behavior do you want that's different?

Comment: @DavidMaze thats exactly what i want :D
I just didn't know if it would really work out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference environment variables in command and args.

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

```
env:
- name: MESSAGE
  value: "hello world"
command: ["/bin/echo"]
args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]
```